# Windows pop-up balloon for PHP & MySQL application

Tags: php, mysql, notifications, balloon

I have a ticketing web application written with PHP and MySQL. I need something like **windows balloon** or **gmail desktop notifier** for Chrome to notify users about some events. For example, when a new ticket arrives to a users, he/she can be notified about it without need to see the application page.

Is there anything for this that can work with PHP and MySQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to build a chrome extension for showing desktop notification of your tickets. To do that, you will need PHP and MySQL at the backend AND the actual Chrome extension written in JavaScript and HTML.
You can write the notification window using JavaScript and HTML packaged inside your Chrome extension.

Here is a link showing how to [build a basic extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html) and here is another one on [desktop notifications](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html). Keep in mind that desktop notifications in Chrome popup outside the browser. However, if you are familiar with JavaScript and HTML, you should be able to achieve what you require.

Keep us posted on your progress and/or if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you have no other choice than to create an add-on/extension for Firefox and/or Chrome.
PHP and MySql are server-side technologies, not client side !

What you have to do is an add-on which will listen to some event or on the web page itself, or directly to the server through an Ajax function.

Have a look at [Add-On SDK for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder)

Answer (score 0):

I never thought about it but as I seen before, forums use this way to warn you that you are not a registered user. It's just a single `div` and a css class defined with `fixed` position.

Hope this help you! هموطن!

Comment: Mahan, what you said could be a solution but not in my case. As I said in my question, I need something that prevent users need to open their pages always. I need something windows balloon.
What you mentioned, just works in web application itself.

Comment: This is not gonna work. 'cause @Mohammad asked for something like windows balloon not in webpage itself.